# Can't see the talent tree in the workshop hero build

Tags: dota-2

I tried to create a build starting from [here](http://www.dota2.com/workshop/builds) and everything looked great until I had to create the ability build :

[image]

As you can see, I can't see the talent tree and, thus, can't save my build because it asks me to fill the 4 missing levels.

Is it a bug or am I just blind?

Answer (score 1):

The Workshop build creator hasn't been updated for Talents, though it recognizes the new Ultimate level timings. I believe the only way to create a build with Talents is from the game itself.

Comment: Hahaha! So how does someone create a build? From the game?

Comment: Torte de Lini must have put in so much effort updating all the guides after the 7.00 update

Comment: Until Valve will provide a good mechanism for builds, the only way left is to create builds in 3rd party apps.